# Can I make the 'read' command tell me how long it took to receive an input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I currently have a script monitoring a reply from a com port. It currently has a 2 second timeout(read -t 2), and if no reply, initiates an action.

Currently, there's an issue where its reaching that timeout unexpectedly. I would like to know by how much exactly its missing it.

Is there a way to have it say how long it took until it successfully read something? I'm trying to have to avoid a bunch of tests while increasing the timeout value and also see the consistency. Thanks.

read -t 2 < /dev/ttyS0; then xxxxx

---

If read fails then action occurs.

Comment: If you run `time read ...` the `real` output line will tell you how long it took the `read` to complete.  `time` is a Bash built-in command.

Comment: How accurate does the measurement result have to be? Are seconds enough?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, seconds is more than fine.

Answer (score 1):

`read` doesn't have this capability built in, but you can combine it with the `time` utility. `time read < /dev/ttyS0` for example will block until it reads something from the device and then print the total time that the call took including the time spent waiting.

If you want to capture to a file instead of displaying on the terminal:

```
{ time read < /dev/ttyS0 ; } 2>time_result
```

If you want to display on the terminal *and* capture in a file:

```
{ time read < /dev/ttyS0 ; } 2> >( tee time_result )
```

Comment: ...though _capturing_ the output of the built-in `time` (and one certainly needs to use the built-in one rather than the out-of-process one to avoid discarding `read`'s result) can be a little tricky, and is maybe worth demonstrating in this answer.

Comment: (see [BashFAQ #32](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032) for some places to start on that).

Comment: That was going to be my next question, is how to get that to print to a file and also work the same way.

Comment: Added some extra examples for capturing the output from `time`.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` and its special variable `SECONDS`:

```
SECONDS=0
read -t 2 < /dev/ttyS0
s=$SECONDS

if [[ $s -lt 2 ]]; then
  echo "less than 2 seconds";
else
  echo "$s seconds";
fi
```